# WinScp: Connection has been unexpectedly closed. server sent command exit status 127

Tags: ssh, winscp

My Server is Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and I am able to connect SSH in Putty, but not able to connect via WinSCP.

When I try to connect via WinSCP it gives below error:

Connection has been unexpectedly closed. server sent command exit status 127

[image]

Comment: This does not look like a programming question. It should go to [su] or a similar site (like AskUbuntu, where you have already asked it -- https://askubuntu.com/q/1111873/280048)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access your sftp from other hosts, please make sure following is installed and configured properly.

- Installed OpenSSH servers
- Configured **sshd_config**

  - PubkeyAuthentication yes
  - Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
- Added your public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
- Start the ssh server with port 22/TCP open 
  `# /etc/init.d/sshd start`
- `# iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 22`

Finally, test 
`$ sftp <login>@<hostname>`